# Find the Rao-Cramer lower bound (Help with Expectation)

Tags: statistics, expected-value, fisher-information

How to find the **Rao-Cramer** lower bound of

$$f(x; \theta) = \dfrac{1}{\theta^2}x \exp(-x/\theta)$$

===================

I know I have to take the $\ln$ of $f(x;\theta)$. I got 
$$\ln(f(x; \theta)) = -2\ln(\theta) + \ln(x)-\frac{x}{θ}.$$

Then I took the **derivative** in order to get the **score function** as $$S(\theta) = \dfrac{\mathrm d \ln(f(x; \theta))}{\mathrm d \theta} = -\dfrac{2}{\theta} + \dfrac{x}{θ^2}$$

The **Fisher information** is equal to 
$$-\mathbb E\left[\dfrac{\mathrm dS(\theta)}{\mathrm d \theta} \right] = \mathbb E \left[-\dfrac{2}{\theta^2} - \dfrac{2x}{\theta^3} \right].$$

I know that I need to get the negative expectation of this, but I'm not sure how to do it. $-\mathbb E(2/\theta^2) = 2/\theta^2$ and $-\mathbb E(2x/\theta^3)$ I think should equal $-2 \theta /\theta^3 = -2/\theta^2$?

It's wrong. Please show me what I have done wrong. **The answer should be** $$\mathcal I(\theta) = 2/\theta^2.$$

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The error is in when you distribute the negative in the Fisher information, you should have $-\frac{2}{\theta^2}+\frac{2x}{\theta^3}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
-\mathbb E\left[\dfrac{\mathrm dS(\theta)}{\mathrm d \theta} \right] = \mathbb E \left[-\dfrac{2}{\theta^2}\, {\bf\color{red}{+}}\, \dfrac{2X}{\theta^3} \right]=-\dfrac{2}{\theta^2}+\dfrac{2\mathbb E[X]}{\theta^3}=-\dfrac{2}{\theta^2}+\dfrac{2\cdot 2\theta}{\theta^3}=\dfrac{2}{\theta^2}.
$$

Comment: Why is the E(X) = 2 θ?

Comment: Calculate and check.

Comment: $\mathbb E[x] = \int_0^\infty x f(x; \theta) \mathrm dx = \int_0^\infty \frac{x^2 \exp(-x/\theta)}{\theta^2} \mathrm dx = 2 \theta$, assuming that $0 \leq x \leq \infty$.

Comment: @NashJ. Look at the original post: the expectation is found there. See third row from the bottom.